# Content size of a UIWebView?

Tags: uiwebview, size

My problems displaying my contents in the `UIWebView`:

1) The text is not displayed until the end

2) Some large gaps are left

[image]

3) The last line is clipped

[image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: It doesn't look like you are facing a technical issue, rather a lack of reading the documentation for the UI components. What steps have you followed to attempt to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

A web-browser HTML might contain spaces or newlines in it. Programmatically remove them.

The last line probably clips because its height is large. Reduce its height.

Comment: Here I change the height, but not work contentFrame = question.frame;
    contentFrame.size.height = question.scrollView.contentSize.height;
    contentFrame.origin.y = 0;
    question.frame = contentFrame;
    contentFrame = labelAnswerA.frame;
    contentFrame.size.height = labelAnswerA.scrollView.contentSize.height+ HTMLTextSize;
    contentFrame.origin.y = question.frame.origin.y+ question.frame.size.height+ HTMLTextSize;
    labelAnswerA.frame = contentFrame;
    contentFrame = labelAnswerB.frame;
    contentFrame.size.height = labelAnswerB.scrollView.contentSize.height+

Comment: HTMLTextSize;
    contentFrame.origin.y = labelAnswerA.frame.origin.y+ labelAnswerA.frame.size.height+ HTMLTextSize;
    labelAnswerB.frame = contentFrame;
    contentFrame = labelAnswerC.frame;
    contentFrame.size.height = labelAnswerC.scrollView.contentSize.height+ HTMLTextSize;
    contentFrame.origin.y = labelAnswerB.frame.origin.y+ labelAnswerB.frame.size.height+ HTMLTextSize;

Comment: labelAnswerC.frame = contentFrame;
    contentFrame = labelAnswerD.frame;
    contentFrame.size.height = labelAnswerD.scrollView.contentSize.height+ HTMLTextSize;
    contentFrame.origin.y = labelAnswerC.frame.origin.y+ labelAnswerC.frame.size.height+ HTMLTextSize;
    labelAnswerD.frame = contentFrame;